# Brackets inside function argument ES5 compatibility

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I'm running the script below in IE11 with no transpilers. However, it returns an "expected identifier" error.

```
var result = Object.values(response.data.reduce(function(r, { boxm, model_no, model_name, qty, type }, index, array) {
      r[boxm] = r[boxm] || { boxm: boxm, lines: [] }
      r[boxm].lines.push({ model_no: model_no.toString(), model_name: model_name, qty: qty, type: type })
      return r
}, {}))
```

I'm guessing it must be this part `{ boxm, model_no, model_name, qty, type }` in the reduce function.

Does someone know how do I convert this into ES5 friendly syntax.

Comment: Just don't destructure the parameter. `Object.values` isn't supported either https://caniuse.com/#search=Object.values

Comment: The not supported part is for sure the deconstruction, but also the Object.values()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The not supported part is for sure the deconstruction, but also the `Object.values`.

To be sure about what you can use or not, there is a website:

https://caniuse.com/#search=Object.values

---

[image]

---

```
var obj = response.data.reduce(function(r, data, index, array) {
  r[data.boxm] = r[data.boxm] || {
    boxm: data.boxm,
    lines: [],
  };

  r[data.boxm].lines.push({
    model_no: data.model_no.toString(),
    model_name: data.model_name,
    qty: data.qty,
    type: data.type,
  });

  return r;
}, {});

var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function(x) {
  return obj[x];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called destructuring, and it's ECMAScript 6 syntax. `Object.values` and the dynamic property name are not supported either. Here's a full ES5 version:

```
//Note that I'm creating Object.values here to make the rest of the code simpler
Object.prototype.values = function(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
        return obj[key];
    });
};

var result = Object.values(response.data.reduce(function(r, curr, index, array) {
    if (!r[curr.boxm]) {
        r[curr.boxm] = {
            boxm: curr.boxm,
            lines: []
        }
    }
    r[curr.boxm].lines.push({
        model_no: curr.model_no.toString(),
        model_name: curr.model_name,
        qty: curr.qty,
        type: curr.type
    });
    return r;
}, {}));
```